# How do I use OCIServerVersion (Oracle) from a C program?

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

FYI: This code is part of an opensource LabView LLB/library/DLL for DB access

My code segment is as follows:

```
#ifdef HAVE_ORACLE
    case oracle_api:
        sprintf(DriverName, "%s\nOracle ", SQL_LV_VERSION);
        retCode = OCIServerVersion (db->srvhp, db->errhp, DriverName + strlen(DriverName), BUFF_SIZE - strlen(DriverName), 0);
        checkerr(db->errhp, retCode, DriverName + strlen(DriverName)); 
        break;
#endif
```

The problem is I keep getting, "OCI_INVALID_HANDLE".

From GDB:

```
(gdb) print retCode
$1 = -2
(gdb) print DriverName
$2 = "sql_LV-1.10\nOracle Error - OCI_INVALID_HANDLE\n\000
(gdb) whatis db->srvhp
type = OCIServer *
```

And my typedef is:

```
/* Typedefs */  
typedef struct {
    MYSQL mysql;
    MYSQL_RES *query_results;
#ifdef HAVE_ODBC
    HENV henv;
    HDBC hdbc;
    HSTMT hstmt;
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_ORACLE
    OCIEnv *envhp;
    OCIError *errhp;
    OCISession *authp;
    OCIServer *srvhp;
    OCISvcCtx *svchp;
#endif
    unsigned short int odbc_driver, db_type;
    } SQL_LV_REF;
```

I'd tried both the service context handle and the server context handle (*which are both non-NULL*).

And I've been able to use the open connection to successfully "SELECT" data in separate DLL calls.

In response to the question, what does OCIServerAttach look like?

```
#ifdef HAVE_ORACLE
case oracle_api:
    sprintf(EasyConnect, "%s:%d/%s", host, (port==0) ? 1521: port, db_nm);
    retCode = OCIEnvCreate((OCIEnv **) &db_ref->envhp, (ub4) OCI_DEFAULT,
                (dvoid *) 0, (dvoid * (*)(dvoid *,size_t)) 0,
                (dvoid * (*)(dvoid *, dvoid *, size_t)) 0,
                (void (*)(dvoid *, dvoid *)) 0, (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0);

        if (retCode != 0) {
            (void) sprintf(debug_str, "OCIEnvCreate failed with retCode = %d.\n", retCode);
            LV_str_cp(debug, debug_str); return(-1);}

        (void) OCIHandleAlloc( (dvoid *) db_ref->envhp, (dvoid **) &db_ref->errhp, OCI_HTYPE_ERROR,
                (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0);   /* server contexts */
        (void) OCIHandleAlloc( (dvoid *) db_ref->envhp, (dvoid **) &db_ref->srvhp, OCI_HTYPE_SERVER,
                        (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0);
        (void) OCIHandleAlloc( (dvoid *) db_ref->envhp, (dvoid **) &db_ref->svchp, OCI_HTYPE_SVCCTX,
                        (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0);
        retCode =  OCIServerAttach( db_ref->srvhp, db_ref->errhp, (text *) EasyConnect,    /* Connect to the target */
                                    strlen((const char *) EasyConnect), 0);
```

Comment: You obtain the svchp from OCIServerAttach.  What does the OCIServerAttach code look like?  Do you check the error that it returns?  Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58234/app_exam.htm for a simple example.

Comment: Thanks but I started from that link to get to the point I am now and I don't see any example code on how to use, OCIServerVersion.

Comment: Some random comments: if you just want the DB version, use OCIServerRelease.  But beware of the [changes with Oracle 18.3](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/some-new-features-of-oracle-instant-client-183), where you really want to use OCIServerRelease2.  Examples OCI calls are in https://github.com/oracle/odpi/blob/master/src/dpiOci.c#L2497-L2518  - you may find it easier to use ODPI-C instead of OCI.

Comment: Thanks, but OCIServerRelease doesn't work either. I keep getting OCI_INVALID_HANDLE no matter what I use for the first parameter,  In the end, the query: `"SELECT Banner FROM v$version WHERE BANNER LIKE 'Oracle%';"` accomplished what I wanted,

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around for the issue, namely, since queries are working, I can use:

```
SELECT Banner FROM v$version WHERE Banner LIKE 'Oracle%'
```

To obtain server information (*as follows*):

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
```

I still would like to see examples of how to use *OCIServerRelease* and *OCIServerVersion*. I think it's important to note that Oracle provided no help or support, they did reach out to sell a service contract though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but since this question/answer comes up on google search, answering it for the people who comes after me :) There is really no magic in OCI APIs- you use the same technique in almost all APIs. All you need to do to get the oracle server version is the following

```
sword rc;
char sver[1024];

if((rc = OCIServerVersion(_service, _error, (text*) sver, (ub4) sizeof(sver), (ub1) OCI_HTYPE_SVCCTX)) != OCI_SUCCESS)
    throw "OCIServerVersion";

std::cout<<"database version:"<<sver;
```

Here

```
OCISvcCtx *_service;
OCIError *_error;
```

You just need to make sure the connections are made correctly to get the server version before calling the API.